# How to run java behind proxychains

Tags: java, proxy, tor, packets

I have a java class in which htmlunit's webclient gets html pages. I want to send the packets through Tor proxy. When I set the proxy in my java code, by setting System properties:

```
System.getproperty("socksProxyHost","127.0.0.1");
System.getproperty("socksProxyPort","9050");
```

, it works correctly. But when I want to use tool ProxyChains,

```
proxychains java -jar MyPackagedJava.jar
```

, it is not work!
In the other words, I want to send htmlunit's packets through ProxyChains. How to do it?

Comment: "it is not work" ... do you have an error message to back that statement up?

Comment: Did you remove the `System.getproperty("socksProxy` lines form your code when you tried?

Comment: [Reply to  Stultuske]: No explicit error...I just send a request to 'ipecho.net/plain' or 'icanhazip.com' and see my IP. It will not change when use proxychains!

Comment: [Reply to ' Oleg 1 ']: Yes.

Comment: [answer to comment by 'Oleg'] If you remove these lines, the packages will be sent via no packages. In the other words, no way to send the packages via proxies of proxychains.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUnit does not use the java proxy settings, you have to configure this during your client setup.
Have a look at [HtmlUnit -Getting started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html); there is a sample for proxy setup.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't send the packets via proxychains' proxies. So, you have to set the proxy in your coding. For example when using HtmlUnit & WebClient object to request a web page, just use the followings:

```
**WebClient webclient;**
if (proxy != null && !proxy.getHost().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        if (proxy.getType() == null || proxy.getType().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")
                || proxy.getType().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("http") ||
                proxy.getType().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("https"))
            webclient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME, proxy.getHost(), proxy.getPort());
        else if (proxy.getType().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("socks")) {
            System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", proxy.getHost());
            System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", String.valueOf(proxy.getPort()));
            webclient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        }
        webclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials(
                proxy.getUsername(), proxy.getPassword(), "", ""));

    } else {
        webclient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    }
```

The object **proxy** is an instance of Proxy class defined below:

```
public class Proxy {
    private String host, username, password,type;
    private int port;


public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Proxy(String host, int port, String username, String password) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}

public String getHost() {
    return this.host;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPort(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public int getPort() {
    return this.port;
}
```

}